# Storing timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm grabbing data from a webpage that returns a timestamp in the following form (which is a string):

`2013-11-09T15:14:48.957604`

How can I interpret this in PHP, and what is the best way to store this in a MySQL database?

Comment: the phase for today is `ISO-8601`  if mysql is any good it will understand that string unaltered. (use a timestamp column)

Comment: Hmm, you can convert it in unix timestamp, like `strtotime('2013-11-09T15:14:48.957604')` and save it as integer(11) value :-) so you can read this as timestamp and convert to any time and date format.

Comment: in php `$d1=new DateTime("2013-11-09T15:14:48.957604");`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store it is to use the MySQL DATETIME data type.  It is specifically meant to handle date/time values, and it works beyond the year 2037, which is the approximate limit using unix timestamps.  MySQL and PHP both handle these values with ease using built in functions/libraries (for PHP, see the DateTime class as mentioned by another commenter).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

I just want to expand on the information given here.

This will convert the string into a DateTime object.

```
$dtObject = new DateTime("2013-11-09T15:14:48.957604");
```

But, in order to store the timestamp in the database there are several requirements.

- Needs to be in Y-m-d H:i:s format.
- MYSQL column type must be [datetime/timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)
- Needs to be a string.

Now in order to get this timestamp into a MYSQL friendly format we need to use the `format` function.

```
$timestamp = $dtObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can now `INSERT` this into the database. You can also output the same way following these [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).